# Is it safe to keep C# Filestream open for long periods of time?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

Inside my web service, I open a filestream to a file on local disk. I keep this around for the lifetime of the service. For every query that comes in, I use the filestream to read the disk.
I do this to avoid having to reopen the filestream on every query. Latency of this path is critical (should less than few ms). I use SSD to keep disk IO time to 0.1ms or less.

Can the filestream 'go bad' (become invalid) over long periods of time (days). Is it safer to just reopen the filestream on every query? If I have to reopen, what's the overhead of constantly reopening a filestream several times a second?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't loading the files contents in static memory if you are worrying about latency? I think the question should be what pattern should you be using instead to access the contents rapidly.

Comment: The file is too big to fit in memory. I have an index which lets me directly seek to the right offset and read from there. It shouldn't be more than 1 IO. Amount of data read is small.

Comment: Have you written a test harness to try having a single file stream open versus opening and closing. I would suggest you try writing a test against this and compare the results.

Comment: A basic test shows no significant difference in perf. But I have not created a stress test that sends real queries, so not sure how this would behave under load. You are right, I should.

Comment: I would be interested to hear your results. If the difference is negligible then i would suggest always closing to limit chance of failure.

Comment: @user201511, if these answers lead you to a conclusion, please accept one as the answer. If not, please comment on the answers why and we can help further.

Comment: If the file is too big to fit in memory, and you want each request to be able to randomly access over the entire file, I'd be immediately thinking of memory mapped files - otherwise, surely you're having to serialize all access to the actual FileStream object anyway?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I do serialize access, when reading from disk. Memory mapping would take up some non-trivial amount of memory, yes? This is a 25GB file and not all of it should be loaded into memory at any one time. I'm not entirely clear how I would manage loading sections of it (which sections, how big, etc). How would that work exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is safe to keep files open as long as you need.

Is it good for your case or not - you need to decide yourself. Re-opening file should not be slow (even on regular drive), but you need to try and measure yourself as no one but you know your exact performance goals.

Comment: Selecting this as the answer, even though the other one gives good advice, since this is the only direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 7):

The only concern I would have leaving the file open is if the application were to fail, for whatever reason, and could not recover from its current location to close the stream; the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point in `KERNEL32` which is used to open the file makes the following statement:

> When an application is finished using the object handle returned by CreateFile, use the CloseHandle function to close the handle. This not only frees up system resources, but can have wider influence on things like sharing the file or device and committing data to disk. Specifics are noted within this topic as appropriate.

So I would think it's much more appropriate to open and close the `FileStream` every single time.

Comment: I agree, leaving a file open for reading for long periods of time seems like a risk and against best practices for open, reading then closing a resource.

Comment: Thanks, it does sound like the right thing to do is to reopen every time.

Comment: @user201511, please remember to mark it as the answer for myself and the rest of the community.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by 'mark it as the answer for myself and the rest of the commnunity'. Do you mean mark this as the accepted answer? I already chose one.